# Asymmetric Encryption in Java: How to avoid different results of the same phrase?

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I know that one characteristic of asymetric encryption is, that if you encryt a text with the public key, you get each time different results.

Is there a way to get always the same result (without RSA)?

Sample-Code:

```
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(
    new RSAPublicKeySpec(
        new BigInteger("83087..."),
        new BigInteger("65537")));

PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(
    new RSAPrivateKeySpec(
        new BigInteger("830874..."),
        new BigInteger("514268...")));


Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "RSA" ); 
cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey );        
cipher.doFinal( "test");
```

Comment: Did you mean Asymmetric? It is about symmetry not time.

Comment: Also I don't see how encrypting (using the same key) would ever get you different results. That would make it impossible to decrypt...

Comment: @ phq youre right, sorry

@Thor84no it is easily possible, for example adding a random number at the end

Comment: @MaxSchmidt That's just being deliberately awkward. It didn't take much to realise I was talking about the *same* data encrypted using the *same* key. You really *don't* want to avoid *different* data having different output when encrypted.

Comment: @Thor84no 
RSA encryption is randomized. For a given public key and a given message, each attempt at encryption yields a distinct sequence of bytes. This is normal and expected; random bytes are injected as part of the padding phase, and not injecting random bytes would result in a weak encryption system. During decryption, the padding bytes are located and removed, and the original message is recovered unscathed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good encryption must give different results, as it hides information more securely. It hides a fact that a *plain text* for two separate *cipher texts* is equal. It's called *semantic security*.

It's achieved by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector.

And yes, of course, the encryption is asymmetric.

Comment: Thanks, but is there an algorithm that doesnt uses an initialization vector even if it is not so secure?

Comment: XOR? :) What's the point of using strong cryptography if you are trying to avoid security? Just waste of resources. Maybe you need integrity/authorship check? Use other crypto-systems then, e.g. signature or MAC. Could you describe exact problem you are solving?

Comment: I need to save encrypted user passwords. Of course I could also create a SHA-Hash of the passwords and if the user lost their password they have to create a new one. But in my special case, I need to decrypt them.  I thought if I use an asymetric encryption and the application only have the public key it would be secure.

To check the password I decrypt it and compared it with the stored password. But this doesnt work if every encryption produces in different results.

Comment: You have to use SHA-hash for authentication. And asymmetrically encrypted password for the storage. Don't decrypt passwords to check. Moreover, better to give users an option to choose store or not a password, because it's different levels of information security requirements.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea
I'm now storing the hashed and the encrypted password. The hashed is used for checking a password and the encrypted to recover them if needed.